# nuxtServerInit with Vuex causes infinite loop laravel and nuxtjs

Tags: laravel, vuex, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs

Im trying to run couple of axios calls in a nuxtjs front-end , laravel backend project with `nuxtServerInit` so they get called at server side.while adding this peice of code

```
async nuxtServerInit({commit}) {
  const usercompany = await this.$axios.get('dashboard/getusercompanyfresh');
  console.log(usercompany)
  if(usercompany.data != undefined && usercompany.data !== '') {
    commit('SET_USERCOMPANY', usercompany.data);
  }

 if(usercompany.data != undefined 
    && usercompany.data !== '' 
    && usercompany.data.firstmade != undefined 
    && usercompany.data.firstmade =='candidate'
 ) {
   const processinfo = await this.$axios.get('dashboard/processinfo')
   console.log(processinfo)
   await commit('SET_PROCESSINFO', processinfo.data);
 }

  const response = await this.$axios.get('company/getcache')
  commit('SET_MAINCACHE',response.data);
 
  const themonths = await this.$axios.get('getmonths')
  commit('months', themonths.data);    
  commit('years');
  commit('days');   
});
```

In my `store/actions.js` the pages will load in localhost but when I build it on my server it goes into an infinite loop.
The result of these calls are bunch of jsons and objects which I can see with console.log but in my server I see this error instead repeating untill I kill node process

The Error

```
 rabter >  WARN  Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs ClientRequest      x
x                              xx rabter >  ERROR  Maximum call stack size exceeded                       x
x                              xx rabter >   at String.replace (<anonymous>)                              x
x                              xx rabter >   at stringifyPrimitive (node_modules/@nuxt/devalue/dist/deva  x
x                              xx rabter >   at stringify (node_modules/@nuxt/devalue/dist/devalue.cjs.j  x
x                              xx rabter >   at node_modules/@nuxt/devalue/dist/devalue.cjs.js:105:79     x
x                              xx rabter >   at Array.map (<anonymous>)                                   x
x                              xx rabter >   at stringify (node_modules/@nuxt/devalue/dist/devalue.cjs.j  x
x                              xx rabter >   at node_modules/@nuxt/devalue/dist/devalue.cjs.js:129:98     x
x                              xx rabter >   at Array.map (<anonymous>)                                   x
x                              xx rabter >   at stringify (node_modules/@nuxt/devalue/dist/devalue.cjs.j  x
x                              xx rabter >   at stringify (node_modules/@nuxt/devalue/dist/devalue.cjs.j
```

this error will not appear on localhost and everything works fine in there
I have also put this in index.js where I export my actions but still the same problem
Thanks for any help

Comment: Do any of the axios requests return null `data`?

Comment: Can you provide us all store data? your state and your mutations?

Answer (score 0):

I have make some changes in your version, can you try this updated nuxtServerInit function?

```
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req }) {
    try {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!req) return

        const usercompany = this.$axios.get('dashboard/getusercompanyfresh')
        console.log(usercompany)

        if (usercompany && usercompany.data) {
          commit('SET_USERCOMPANY', usercompany.data)
        }

        if (
          usercompany &&
          usercompany.data &&
          usercompany.data.firstmade &&
          usercompany.data.firstmade === 'candidate'
        ) {
          const processinfo = this.$axios.get('dashboard/processinfo')
          console.log(processinfo)
          commit('SET_PROCESSINFO', processinfo.data)
        }

        const response = this.$axios.get('company/getcache')
        if (response && response.data) {
          commit('SET_MAINCACHE', response.data)
        }

        const themonths = this.$axios.get('getmonths')
        if (themonths && themonths.data) {
          commit('months', themonths.data)
        }
        commit('years')
        commit('days')
        resolve(true)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  },
```